# AttributeError: type object 'RewriterConfig' has no attribute 'ON'

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror

I ran a Tensorflow programme and the error returned this...

> File
>   "/Users/Rahul/desktop/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 72, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
>       layout_optimizer = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.ON) AttributeError: type object 'RewriterConfig' has no attribute 'ON'

this is the code from line 69 to 77 -->

```
  if optimize_graph:

  logging.info('Graph Rewriter optimizations enabled')
  rewrite_options = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig(
      layout_optimizer = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.ON)
  rewrite_options.optimizers.append('pruning')
  rewrite_options.optimizers.append('constfold')
  rewrite_options.optimizers.append('layout')
  graph_options = tf.GraphOptions(
      rewrite_options = rewrite_options, infer_shapes=True)
```

Can anyone help, i have no clue where to go

Comment: Why have you copy/pasted the traceback but gone to the extra effort of screenshotting the code and hosting it off-site? Please do not post images of code, it should be included in your question. Links can expire and it also means we would have to write any code out verbatim just to set up a test-case.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use a more recent version of TensorFlow (a nightly version if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tensorflow are you using? Could you use version 1.4 or newer?